# When should I use the EntityManger detach method?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have the following code where em is the EntityManager:

```
Query query = em.createQuery( "SELECT e FROM TODO e " );
ret = (TODO) query.getSingleResult();
em.detach( ret );
return ret;
```

Once I return ret from this method (and leave the class) won't the entity manager detach anyway?  Why would I ever need to use the detach method?

Comment: It will detach when your session is closed. You would want to detach the entity, for example, if you wanted to modify it without the changes being reflected in the database.

Comment: Another reason might be to pass the entity to another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll detach an entity before handing it off to a user method (perhaps a callback method) when that callback method is expected to be able to access (read), but not influence/change the object during the course of my transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Entities automatically detached when transaction ends.
Sometimes you want to detach a entity before because you want to make changes in entity that you dont want to be persisted automatically.